# How to redirect to you tube using PHP

Tags: php, redirect, youtube

i have a site it running on a platform called "photo store" its a PHP site. there is image i want some one click that image redirect to my you tube channel but problem is all pages loading from template.so i did some coding and add a few line with if statement first i did only echo that works but when i try to redirect to YouTube it wand load 500 error coming can anyone help me??

this is a code

```html
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'cart.php') or strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'index.php')) // Clear the crumbs if coming from the cart or index
        unset($_SESSION['crumbsSession']);

    try
    {   
        //$useGalleryID = $galleryID; // Original untouched gallery ID
        $useMediaID = $mediaID; // Original untouched media ID

        if(!$mediaID) // Make sure a media ID was passed
            $smarty->assign('noAccess',1);
        else
        {
            if($config['EncryptIDs']) // Decrypt IDs
            {
                $mediaID = k_decrypt($mediaID);
                $useGalleryID = k_encrypt($_SESSION['id']);
            }
            else
                $useGalleryID = $_SESSION['id'];

            //echo $mediaID;

            idCheck($mediaID); // Make sure ID is numeric


            $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}media WHERE media_id = '{$mediaID}'";
            $mediaInfo = new mediaList($sql);


            if($mediaInfo->getRows())
            {
                if($mediaID==985){
                    echo $mediaID;
                    window.location.replace("http://www.youtube.com");

                }
                else{
                $media = $mediaInfo->getSingleMediaDetails('preview');
                $galleryIDArray = $mediaInfo->getMediaGalleryIDs(); // Get an array of galleries this media is in

                if(@!in_array($mediaID,$_SESSION['viewedMedia'])) // See if media has already been viewed
                {
                    $newMediaViews = $media['views']+1;
                    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE {$dbinfo[pre]}media SET views='{$newMediaViews}' WHERE media_id = '{$mediaID}'"); // Update views
                    $media['views'] = $newMediaViews; // Update the array so the count shown is the new count
                    $_SESSION['viewedMedia'][] = $mediaID;
                }

                //print_r($media); exit;

                /*
                if(!$_SESSION['crumbsSession']) // Get a crumb trail - doesn't work for contibutors yet
                {                   
                    @$galleryInfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}media_galleries WHERE gmedia_id = '{$mediaID}' ORDER BY mg_id LIMIT 1"));
                    if($galleryInfo['gallery_id'])
                    {
                        $galleriesMainPageLink['page'] = "gallery.php?mode=gallery";
                        $_SESSION['galleriesData'][0]['linkto'] = linkto($galleriesMainPageLink); // Check for SEO
                        $_SESSION['galleriesData'][0]['name'] = $lang['galleries']; //

                        $_SESSION['crumbsSession'] = galleryCrumbsFull($galleryInfo['gallery_id']);
                    }
                }
                */

                // Check for video sample
                $mediaInfo2 = new mediaTools($mediaID);             

                if($media['dsp_type'] == 'video') // Make sure the DSP type is set to video
                {
                    if($video = $mediaInfo2->getVidSampleInfoFromDB()) // Make sure video file exists
                    {

                        $videoCheck = $mediaInfo2->verifyVidSampleExists();
                        if($videoCheck['status']) { // Make sure the video exists

                            //print_k($videoCheck); exit;

                            if($videoCheck['url'] and $config['passVideoThroughPHP'] === false)
                                $video['url'] = $videoCheck['url']; // Use URL method
                            else
                                $video['url'] = $config['settings']['site_url'].'/video.php?mediaID='.$media['encryptedID']; // Use PHP pass-through

                            //echo $video['url']; exit;

                            //print_k($video);
                            $media['videoStatus'] = 1;
                            $media['videoInfo'] = $video;

                        } else {
                            $media['videoStatus'] = 0;  
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        $media['videoStatus'] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    /*
                    * Get an estimated preview width and height
                    */
                    $sample = $mediaInfo2->getSampleInfoFromDB();   
                    $sampleSize = getScaledSizeNoSource($sample['sample_width'],$sample['sample_height'],$config['settings']['preview_size'],$crop=0);              
                    $media['previewWidth'] = $sampleSize[0];
                    $media['previewHeight'] = $sampleSize[1];
                }

                $mediaPrice = getMediaPrice($media); // Get the media price based on the license
                $mediaCredits = getMediaCredits($media); // Get the media credits based on the license

                // Get category ID - Make sure member has access to category - maybe add this later

                $galleryIDArrayFlat = ($galleryIDArray) ? implode(",",$galleryIDArray) : 0;

                /*
                * Prints *****************************************************************************************************************************
                */
                $galleryPrintsResult = mysqli_query($db,
                    "
                    SELECT DISTINCT(item_id) 
                    FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries 
                    LEFT JOIN {$dbinfo[pre]}prints 
                    ON {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries.item_id = {$dbinfo[pre]}prints.print_id
                    WHERE {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries.gallery_id IN ({$galleryIDArrayFlat}) 
                    AND {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries.mgrarea = 'prints' 
                    AND ({$dbinfo[pre]}prints.attachment = 'media' OR {$dbinfo[pre]}prints.attachment = 'both')
                    "
                ); // Find out which prints are assigned to galleries this photo is in
                $galleryPrintsRows = mysqli_num_rows($galleryPrintsResult);
                while($galleryPrint = mysqli_fetch_array($galleryPrintsResult))
                    $printIDArray[] = $galleryPrint['item_id'];

                $mediaPrintsResult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}media_prints WHERE media_id = '{$mediaID}'"); // Find what prints have been directly assigned to this photo //  GROUP BY print_id
                $mediaPrintsRows = mysqli_num_rows($mediaPrintsResult);
                //echo $mediaPrintsRows; exit; // Testing
                while($mediaPrint = mysqli_fetch_array($mediaPrintsResult))
                {
                    if($mediaPrint['printgrp_id']) // Is a group assignment
                    {
                        // Select print groups
                        $mediaPrintsGroupsResult = mysqli_query($db,
                            "
                                SELECT * 
                                FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}prints 
                                LEFT JOIN {$dbinfo[pre]}groupids 
                                ON {$dbinfo[pre]}prints.print_id = {$dbinfo[pre]}groupids.item_id 
                                WHERE {$dbinfo[pre]}groupids.group_id = '{$mediaPrint[printgrp_id]}' 
                                AND {$dbinfo[pre]}prints.active = 1 
                                AND {$dbinfo[pre]}prints.deleted = 0 
                                AND {$dbinfo[pre]}groupids.mgrarea = 'prints'
                            "
                        );
                        //$pgRows = mysqli_num_rows($mediaPrintsGroupsResult); // Testing
                        //echo $pgRows;
                        while($mediaPrintsGroup = mysqli_fetch_array($mediaPrintsGroupsResult))
                            $printIDArray[] = $mediaPrintsGroup['print_id'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $printIDArray[] = $mediaPrint['print_id'];

                        if($mediaPrint['customized'])
                        {
                            $printCustomizedIDs[] =  $mediaPrint['print_id']; // Add this ID to the custom array list
                            $customPrint[$mediaPrint['print_id']] = $mediaPrint; // Get the actual values for the custom item
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($printIDArray)
                    $printsIDArrayFlat = implode(",",$printIDArray);
                else
                    $printsIDArrayFlat = 0;

                // Now that we have the print ID array select the prints that the customer has access to and assign them to smarty
                $printsResult = mysqli_query($db,
                    "
                    SELECT *
                    FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}prints
                    LEFT JOIN {$dbinfo[pre]}perms
                    ON ({$dbinfo[pre]}prints.print_id = {$dbinfo[pre]}perms.item_id AND {$dbinfo[pre]}perms.perm_area = 'prints') 
                    WHERE ({$dbinfo[pre]}prints.print_id IN ({$printsIDArrayFlat}) OR {$dbinfo[pre]}prints.all_galleries = 1) 
                    AND {$dbinfo[pre]}prints.active = 1 
                    AND {$dbinfo[pre]}prints.deleted = 0
                    AND ({$dbinfo[pre]}prints.everyone = 1 OR {$dbinfo[pre]}perms.perm_value IN ({$memberPermissionsForDB}))
                    ORDER BY {$dbinfo[pre]}prints.sortorder
                    "
                );
                if($returnRows = mysqli_num_rows($printsResult))
                {
                    while($print = mysqli_fetch_assoc($printsResult))
                    {
                        $print['price'] = defaultPrice($print['price']); // Make sure to assign a default price if needed
                        $print['credits'] = defaultCredits($print['credits']); // Make sure to assign default credits if needed

                        /*
                        * Custom Pricing calculations
                        */
                        if(@in_array($print['print_id'],$printCustomizedIDs))
                        {
                            $print['price_calc'] = $customPrint[$print['print_id']]['price_calc'];
                            $print['price'] = defaultPrice($customPrint[$print['print_id']]['price']);
                            $print['credits'] = defaultCredits($customPrint[$print['print_id']]['credits']);
                            $print['credits_calc'] = $customPrint[$print['print_id']]['credits_calc'];                          
                            $print['quantity'] = $customPrint[$print['print_id']]['quantity']; 
                        }

                        /*
                        * Advanced Pricing calculations
                        */
                        switch($print['price_calc'])
                        {
                            case 'add':
                                $print['price'] = $mediaPrice + $print['price'];
                            break;
                            case 'sub':
                                $print['price'] = $mediaPrice - $print['price'];
                            break;
                            case 'mult':
                                $print['price'] = $mediaPrice * $print['price'];
                            break;
                        }   


                        switch($print['credits_calc'])
                        {
                            case 'add':
                                $print['credits'] = $mediaCredits + $print['credits'];
                            break;
                            case 'sub':
                                $print['credits'] = $mediaCredits - $print['credits'];
                            break;
                            case 'mult':
                                $print['credits'] = $mediaCredits * $print['credits'];
                            break;
                        }

                        //echo $mediaCredits.'-'.$print['credits'].'-'.$print['credits_calc']."/";

                        if($print['quantity'] != '0') // Make sure the quantity is other than 0
                        {
                            $printsArray[$print['print_id']] = printsList($print,$mediaID);

                            $optionsResult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT og_id FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}option_grp WHERE parent_type = 'prints' AND parent_id = '{$print[print_id]}' AND deleted = 0"); // See if there are any options for this item
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($optionsResult))
                            {
                                $printsArray[$print['print_id']]['addToCartLink'] = $printsArray[$print['print_id']]['linkto'];  // Workbox popup
                                $printsArray[$print['print_id']]['directToCart'] = false;    // Workbox popup
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if($config['EncryptIDs'])
                                    $printsArray[$print['print_id']]['addToCartLink'] = "{$siteURL}/cart.php?mode=add&type=print&id=".$printsArray[$print['print_id']]['encryptedID']."&mediaID={$media[encryptedID]}"; // Direct to cart
                                else
                                    $printsArray[$print['print_id']]['addToCartLink'] = "{$siteURL}/cart.php?mode=add&type=print&id={$print[print_id]}&mediaID={$media[media_id]}"; // Direct to cart                               

                                $printsArray[$print['print_id']]['directToCart'] = true;     // Direct to cart
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $smarty->assign('printRows',$returnRows);
                    $smarty->assign('prints',$printsArray);
                }

                /*
                * Digital Files *****************************************************************************************************************************
                */
                require_once 'media.details.inc.php';

                /*
                * Products *****************************************************************************************************************************
                */
                $galleryProductsResult = mysqli_query($db,
                    "
                    SELECT DISTINCT(item_id) 
                    FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries 
                    LEFT JOIN {$dbinfo[pre]}products 
                    ON {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries.item_id = {$dbinfo[pre]}products.prod_id
                    WHERE {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries.gallery_id IN ({$galleryIDArrayFlat}) 
                    AND {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries.mgrarea = 'products' 
                    AND ({$dbinfo[pre]}products.attachment = 'media' OR {$dbinfo[pre]}products.attachment = 'both')
                    "
                ); // Find out which products are assigned to galleries this photo is in
                $galleryProductsRows = mysqli_num_rows($galleryProductsResult);
                while($galleryProduct = mysqli_fetch_array($galleryProductsResult))
                    $productIDsArray[] = $galleryProduct['item_id'];

                $mediaProductsResult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}media_products WHERE media_id = '{$mediaID}'"); // Find what products have been directly assigned to this photo //  GROUP BY prod_id
                $mediaProductsRows = mysqli_num_rows($mediaProductsResult);
                while($mediaProduct = mysqli_fetch_array($mediaProductsResult))
                {
                    if($mediaProduct['prodgrp_id']) // Is a group assignment
                    {
                        // Select product groups
                        $mediaProductsGroupsResult = mysqli_query($db,
                            "
                                SELECT * 
                                FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}products 
                                LEFT JOIN {$dbinfo[pre]}groupids 
                                ON {$dbinfo[pre]}products.prod_id = {$dbinfo[pre]}groupids.item_id 
                                WHERE {$dbinfo[pre]}groupids.group_id = '{$mediaProduct[prodgrp_id]}' 
                                AND {$dbinfo[pre]}products.active = 1 
                                AND {$dbinfo[pre]}products.deleted = 0 
                                AND {$dbinfo[pre]}groupids.mgrarea = 'products'
                            "
                        );
                        while($mediaProductsGroup = mysqli_fetch_array($mediaProductsGroupsResult))
                            $productIDsArray[] = $mediaProductsGroup['prod_id'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $productIDsArray[] = $mediaProduct['prod_id'];

                        if($mediaProduct['customized'])
                        {
                            $productCustomizedIDs[] =  $mediaProduct['prod_id']; // Add this ID to the custom array list
                            $customProduct[$mediaProduct['prod_id']] = $mediaProduct; // Get the actual values for the custom item
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($productIDsArray)
                    $productIDsArrayFlat = implode(",",$productIDsArray);
                else
                    $productIDsArrayFlat = 0;

                //print_r($productCustomizedIDs); exit;

                // Now that we have the product ID array select the products that the customer has access to and assign them to smarty
                $productsResult = mysqli_query($db,
                    "
                    SELECT *
                    FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}products
                    LEFT JOIN {$dbinfo[pre]}perms
                    ON ({$dbinfo[pre]}products.prod_id = {$dbinfo[pre]}perms.item_id AND {$dbinfo[pre]}perms.perm_area = 'products') 
                    WHERE ({$dbinfo[pre]}products.prod_id IN ({$productIDsArrayFlat}) OR {$dbinfo[pre]}products.all_galleries = 1) 
                    AND {$dbinfo[pre]}products.active = 1 
                    AND {$dbinfo[pre]}products.deleted = 0
                    AND ({$dbinfo[pre]}products.everyone = 1 OR {$dbinfo[pre]}perms.perm_value IN ({$memberPermissionsForDB}))
                    ORDER BY {$dbinfo[pre]}products.sortorder
                    "
                );
                if($returnRows = mysqli_num_rows($productsResult))
                {   
                    while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($productsResult))
                    {
                        $product['price'] = defaultPrice($product['price']); // Make sure to assign a default price if needed
                        $product['credits'] = defaultCredits($product['credits']); // Make sure to assign default credits if needed

                        /*
                        * Custom Pricing calculations
                        */
                        if(@in_array($product['prod_id'],$productCustomizedIDs))
                        {
                            $product['price_calc'] = $customProduct[$product['prod_id']]['price_calc'];
                            $product['price'] = defaultPrice($customProduct[$product['prod_id']]['price']);
                            $product['credits'] = defaultCredits($customProduct[$product['prod_id']]['credits']);
                            $product['credits_calc'] = $customProduct[$product['prod_id']]['credits_calc'];                         
                            $product['quantity'] = $customProduct[$product['prod_id']]['quantity']; 
                        }

                        /*
                        * Advanced Pricing calculations
                        */
                        switch($product['price_calc'])
                        {
                            case 'add':
                                $product['price'] = $mediaPrice + $product['price'];
                            break;
                            case 'sub':
                                $product['price'] = $mediaPrice - $product['price'];
                            break;
                            case 'mult':
                                $product['price'] = $mediaPrice * $product['price'];
                            break;
                        }   


                        switch($product['credits_calc'])
                        {
                            case 'add':
                                $product['credits'] = $mediaCredits + $product['credits'];
                            break;
                            case 'sub':
                                $product['credits'] = $mediaCredits - $product['credits'];
                            break;
                            case 'mult':
                                $product['credits'] = $mediaCredits * $product['credits'];
                            break;
                        }

                        if($product['quantity'] != '0') // Make sure the quantity is other than 0
                        {

                            if($product['product_type'] == '1') // Check if this is a media based product
                                $productsArray[$product['prod_id']] = productsList($product,$mediaID); // Media based
                            else
                                $productsArray[$product['prod_id']] = productsList($product,false); // Stand Alone

                            $optionsResult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT og_id FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}option_grp WHERE parent_type = 'products' AND parent_id = '{$product[prod_id]}' AND deleted = 0"); // See if there are any options for this item
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($optionsResult))
                            {
                                $productsArray[$product['prod_id']]['addToCartLink'] = $productsArray[$product['prod_id']]['linkto'];    // Workbox popup
                                $productsArray[$product['prod_id']]['directToCart'] = false;     // Workbox popup
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if($config['EncryptIDs'])
                                {
                                    $cartLink = "{$siteURL}/cart.php?mode=add&type=product&id=".$productsArray[$product['prod_id']]['encryptedID'];
                                    if($product['product_type'] == '1') $cartLink .= "&mediaID={$media[encryptedID]}";
                                    $productsArray[$product['prod_id']]['addToCartLink'] = $cartLink; // Direct to cart
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $cartLink = "{$siteURL}/cart.php?mode=add&type=product&id={$product[prod_id]}";
                                    if($product['product_type'] == '1') $cartLink .= "&mediaID={$media[media_id]}";
                                    $productsArray[$product['prod_id']]['addToCartLink'] = $cartLink; // Direct to cart
                                }

                                $productsArray[$product['prod_id']]['directToCart'] = true;  // Direct to cart
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $smarty->assign('productRows',$returnRows);
                    $smarty->assign('products',$productsArray);
                }


                /*
                * Collections *****************************************************************************************************************************
                */
                $galleryCollectionsResult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT item_id FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries WHERE mgrarea = 'collections' AND gallery_id IN ({$galleryIDArrayFlat})"); // Find collections from galleries
                $galleryCollectionsRows = mysqli_num_rows($galleryCollectionsResult);               
                if($galleryCollectionsRows)
                {
                    while($galleryCollection = mysqli_fetch_array($galleryCollectionsResult))
                        $collectionIDs[] = $galleryCollection['item_id']; 
                }

                $mediaCollectionsResult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT coll_id FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}media_collections WHERE cmedia_id = '{$mediaID}'"); // Find collections this item is directly in
                $mediaCollectionsRows = mysqli_num_rows($mediaCollectionsResult);               
                if($mediaCollectionsRows)
                {
                    while($mediaCollection = mysqli_fetch_array($mediaCollectionsResult))
                        $collectionIDs[] = $mediaCollection['coll_id']; 
                }

                if($collectionIDs) // Only do if some were found
                {
                    $collectionIDsFlat = implode(',',$collectionIDs);

                    $collectionsResult = mysqli_query($db,
                        "
                        SELECT *
                        FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}collections 
                        LEFT JOIN {$dbinfo[pre]}perms
                        ON ({$dbinfo[pre]}collections.coll_id = {$dbinfo[pre]}perms.item_id AND {$dbinfo[pre]}perms.perm_area = 'collections') 
                        WHERE {$dbinfo[pre]}collections.active = 1 
                        AND {$dbinfo[pre]}collections.deleted = 0
                        AND ({$dbinfo[pre]}collections.everyone = 1 OR {$dbinfo[pre]}perms.perm_value IN ({$memberPermissionsForDB}))
                        AND ({$dbinfo[pre]}collections.quantity = '' OR {$dbinfo[pre]}collections.quantity > '0') 
                        AND {$dbinfo[pre]}collections.coll_id IN ({$collectionIDsFlat})
                        ORDER BY {$dbinfo[pre]}collections.sortorder
                        "
                    ); // Select collections that member has access to
                    if($returnRows = mysqli_num_rows($collectionsResult))
                    {
                        while($collections = mysqli_fetch_array($collectionsResult))
                        {
                            $collectionsArray[$collections['coll_id']] = collectionsList($collections);
                            $collectionsWithAccess[] = $collections['coll_id'];
                        }

                        $smarty->assign('collectionRows',$returnRows);
                        $smarty->assign('collections',$collectionsArray);
                    }
                }

                /*
                * Packages *****************************************************************************************************************************
                */

                /*
                $galleryPackagesResult = mysqli_query($db,
                    "
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}packages 
                    WHERE all_galleries = 1 
                    AND (attachment = 'media' OR attachment = 'both')
                    "
                ); // Find packages that are assigned to all galleries and are attached to media or both
                $galleryPackagesRows = mysqli_num_rows($galleryPackagesResult);
                while($galleryPackage = mysqli_fetch_array($galleryPackagesResult))
                    $packageIDsArray[] = $galleryPackage['pack_id'];
                */

                $galleryPackagesResult = mysqli_query($db,
                    "
                    SELECT DISTINCT(item_id) 
                    FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries 
                    LEFT JOIN {$dbinfo[pre]}packages 
                    ON {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries.item_id = {$dbinfo[pre]}packages.pack_id
                    WHERE {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries.gallery_id IN ({$galleryIDArrayFlat}) 
                    AND {$dbinfo[pre]}item_galleries.mgrarea = 'packages' 
                    AND ({$dbinfo[pre]}packages.attachment = 'media' OR {$dbinfo[pre]}packages.attachment = 'both') 
                    "
                ); // Find out which packages are assigned to galleries this photo is in or all galleries and attached to media or both
                $galleryPackagesRows = mysqli_num_rows($galleryPackagesResult);
                while($galleryPackage = mysqli_fetch_array($galleryPackagesResult))
                    $packageIDsArray[] = $galleryPackage['item_id'];

                //print_r($packageIDsArray); // Testing

                $mediaPackagesResult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM {$dbinfo[pre]}media_packages
```

Comment: You should only post code relevant to your question, not your entire PHP file.

Comment: window.location.replace("http://www.youtube.com"); - this is not PHP

Answer (score 0):

window.location.replace("http://www.youtube.com"); is wrong

use thins:

```
header("Location: http://www.youtube.com");
exit;
```

Remember that this must be called before any actual output is sent